# need to know how to interrupt all pthreads

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, signals

In Linux, I am emulating an embedded system that has one thread that gets messages delivered to the outside world.  If some thread detects an insurmountable problem, my goal is to stop all the other threads in their tracks (leaving useful stack traces) and allow only the message delivery thread to continue.  So in my emulation environment, I want to "pthread_kill(tid, SIGnal)" each "tid". (I have a list.  I'm using SIGTSTP.)  Unfortunately, only one thread is getting the signal.  "sigprocmask()" is not able to unmask the signal.  Here is my current (non-working) handler:

```
void
wait_until_death(int sig)
{
    sigset_t mask;    
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, sig);
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL);
    for (;;)
        pause();
}
```

I get verification that all the pthread_kill()'s get invoked, but only one thread has the handler in the stack trace.  Can this be done?

Comment: Did you look at `pthread_cancel()`? If pthread has asynchronous cancellation type, it will be killed immediately at `pthread_cancel()` call.

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe.  If my "cleanup handler" calls this wait_until_death function, I can skip the signaling stuff altogether.  Thank you!

Comment: It effectively does a longjmp to the site of the pthread_cleanup_push(), yielding a useless stack trace.  Thank you for the thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This minimal example seems to function in the manner you want - all the threads except the main thread end up waiting in `wait_until_death()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NTHREADS 10
pthread_barrier_t barrier;

void
wait_until_death(int sig)
{
    sigset_t mask;
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, sig);
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL);
    for (;;)
        pause();
}

void *thread_func(void *arg)
{
    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);

    for (;;)
        pause();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int thread_signal = SIGTSTP;
    const struct sigaction sa = { .sa_handler = wait_until_death };
    int i;
    pthread_t thread[NTHREADS];

    pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, NTHREADS + 1);
    sigaction(thread_signal, &sa, NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++)
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, thread_func, NULL);

    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);

    for (i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++)
        pthread_kill(thread[i], thread_signal);

    fprintf(stderr, "All threads signalled.\n");

    for (;;)
        pause();

    return 0;
}
```

Note that unblocking the signal in the `wait_until_death()` isn't required: the signal mask is per-thread, and the thread that is executing the signal handler isn't going to be signalled again.

Presumably the problem is in how you are installing the signal handler, or setting up thread signal masks.

Comment: I replaced the last three lines with a call to abort() and found the problem.  Two of the 10 threads did not have a signal handling stack frame.  The process was aborted before the signal was delivered to the threads.  In my "real work", 4 of 5 threads did not have a signal stack frame leading me to believe they were not going to be delivered.  With a micro-sleep added, they were.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible. The problem is that some of the threads you stop may hold locks that the thread you want to continue running requires in order to continue making forward progress. Just abandon this idea entirely. Trust me, this will only cause you great pain.

If you literally must do it, have all the other threads call a conditional yielding point at known safe places where they hold no lock that can prevent any other thread from reaching its next conditional yielding point. But this is *very* difficult to get right and is very prone to deadlock and I strongly advise not trying it.

Comment: The "write out messages" thread ignores locks once the "we are panic"-ed state is reached.  Messaging output goes via write(2) to an fd -- not stdio.  But I need to be sure the other threads are all stopped first.  Whether it can be gotten to work or not, it is unclear what I am misunderstanding about why the signals are not getting delivered. :(

Comment: You can't ignore locks for two reasons. First, all you need to do is call one library function that acquires a lock and boom. Second, you may notice the panic state too late, getting stuck on a lock before you notice.

Comment: I think you're right, but I'd like to know why the signals weren't delivered to more than one thread anyway.  Just for the sake of understanding without the inconvenience of reading both glibc and kernel signal handling code. :)  Call me lazy...